# How do I use pause() in Phaser 3 to stop at a specific frame?

Tags: phaser-framework

I have a sprite with 6 frames, and when I click on a button I want to show the frame 3, for example. I'm try this code, but it's still stopping in frame 1.

```
function preload (){
    this.load.spritesheet('info', 'images/info.png', { frameWidth: 550, frameHeight: 400 });
}

function create (){
    var infos = this.add.sprite(275,200,"info")
    this.anims.create({
    key: "informations",
    frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers("info", { start: 0, end: 6 }),
    frameRate: 10,
    repeat: -1
    });

    // I'm try to show the frame 3 here.
    informations.pause(3);
    
    // When I play, the animation work!
    //infos.anims.play("informations", true);

}
```

I found the documentation for [pause( [atFrame] )](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.GameObjects.Components.Animation.html#pause__anchor), but it isn't working.

Answer (score 3):

[`atFrame`](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.GameObjects.Components.Animation.html#pause__anchor) is actually of type `Phaser.Animations.AnimationFrame`. So you need to pass one of those.

You can get one of these types by calling `infos.anims.currentAnim.frames[0]` for example, where `0` is the index of the frame you want.

```
// Assuming you want the third actual frame:
infos.anims.pause(infos.anims.currentAnim.frames[2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

As in Phaser 3.6

it goes with

```
const anim_1 = this.add.sprite(size.halfWidth, size.halfHeight, 'anim_1');
anim_1.displayHeight = size.height;
anim_1.scaleX = anim_1.scaleY;

this.anims.create({
      key: 'anim_1',
      frames: this.anims.generateFrameNames('anim_1', { prefix: 'anim_', suffix: '.png', start: 0, end: 119, zeroPad: 3, }),
      frameRate: 30,
});
anim_1.anims.setCurrentFrame(this.anims.get('anim_1').frames[0]);
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?